# JQuery setTimeout - any more efficient way to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

So Im just toggling and removing some classes at small intervals - I'm pretty new to JS and JQuery but I've done this, which works:

```
function priceTable() {
    setTimeout(function(){$("#price-table-1").toggleClass("price-table-highlight");  },1000);
    setTimeout(function(){$("#price-table-1").removeClass("price-table-highlight");  },2000);
    setTimeout(function(){$("#price-table-2").toggleClass("price-table-highlight");  },2000);
    setTimeout(function(){$("#price-table-2").removeClass("price-table-highlight");  },3000);
    setTimeout(function(){$("#price-table-3").toggleClass("price-table-highlight");  },3000);
    setTimeout(function(){$("#price-table-3").removeClass("price-table-highlight");  },4000); 
}
```

However, there seems to be an awful lot of repetition - is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: It's a little odd to explain but a simplified way would be to say that three identical boxes (with different ID's) have a black border, after 1 second the first box changes to blue, and then back again - followed by the second and the third - if that makes sense?

Comment: for starters, you could store the jQuery elements into some variables and not call the jQuery function twice for the same element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for jQuery animation methods, using the `delay` method works fine.  for other jQuery methods, might I recommend [jquery.wait](https://github.com/madbook/jquery.wait), which works similarly to `delay` but for all jQuery methods.  your code then becomes

```
function priceTable() {
  $('#price-table-1').wait(1000).toggleClass('price-table-highlight').wait(1000).removeClass('price-table-highlight');
  $('#price-table-2').wait(2000).toggleClass('price-table-highlight').wait(1000).removeClass('price-table-highlight');
  $('#price-table-2').wait(3000).toggleClass('price-table-highlight').wait(1000).removeClass('price-table-highlight');
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks like a nice solution. I'll accept the answer once I've tried it out.

Comment: Only just realised this means another HTTP request, which ideally I'd avoid.

Comment: my recommendation is to either use a build script to automatically concat and minify your production code, or just copy past the plugin into your main script.

Answer (score 0):

You can DRY you id identifiers using simple iteration.

```
timer = 1000;
for( pricetableindex = 1; pricetableindex <=3; pricetableindex++ ){
    .....unction(){$("#price-table-"+pricetableindex).toggle...  ), timer);
    .....unction(){$("#price-table-"+pricetableindex).remove...  ), timer+=1000);
```

This is the main selling point for having duplicate syntax to access object members, dot syntax as well as array notation.

```
obj.member1 syntax does not allow this kind of manipulation, while 
obj["member1"] does.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function priceTable() {
    var table_count = 3;

    for(var i = 0; i < table_count; i++) {
        // jQuery
        $('#price-table-' + i).delay(1000)
                              .animate({ "background-color": "blue" })
                              .delay(1000)
                              .animate({ "background-color": "black" });

        // jQuery UI (http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/)
        $('#price-table-' + i).delay(1000)
                              .addClass("price-table-highlight", 0) // 0 is important
                              .delay(1000)
                              .removeClass("price-table-highlight");

    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a nice solution but for some reason doesn't work - I don't get any JS errors but the classes don't toggle.

Comment: Try this updated solution.  I forgot that .toggleClass() calls aren't added to the fx queue, so won't wait for .delay().  Using .animate() with jQuery will have the desired effect, or the enhanced .addClass() from jQuery UI, which supports a duration, and thus the fx queue (hence the second parameter 0 to distinguish the UI version from the core version).  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you have no restriction on the blue/black color swapping, I would use jQuerys `pulsate` (doc can be found [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Pulsate)) effect:

```
function priceTable() {
  $("#price-table-1").effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);
  $("#price-table-2").effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);
  $("#price-table-3").effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);
}
```

Only downside of this: it pulsates the whole element. So I suggest to NOT use the above exactly like above (as all the text within the #price-tables will fade-in and -out, too).
What the pulsate does is, it pulsates the opacity of the element it is applied to. So you could, for example, underlay your price-tables with an empty div and the appropriate background-color.

Comment: I'm actually using a CSS3 transition to change the box shadow - just seemed a bit easier to explain with borders.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out combinations of jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) functions to achieve your result.

The [jQuery UI plug-in](http://jqueryui.com/addClass/) (which you may already be using? toggleClass is one of their methods, but I gather it is present in jQuery core and extended in jQuery-UI) can animate whole classes as well. It would be something like this:

```
function priceTable() {
    $("#price-table-1").toggleClass("price-table-highlight",1).delay(1000).toggleClass("price-table-highlight", 1);
}
```

Not strictly 'more efficient' as it requires a whole additional library, but certainly less code. I don't know if you would be able to start an animation queue with a `.delay` call or if you would have to set a timeout function to begin the animations on the `price-table-2` and `3` id elements.

Comment: Seems a bit crazy to add another library - i'm actually using a CSS3 transition to change the box shadow - just seemed a bit easier to explain with borders.

Comment: @user319940 ah, I'm not up to speed on CSS3 transitions, but it's my understanding that they're largely designed to replace JS-type animations. If you're comfortable with it being modern-browser-only, then I encourage you to stick with the CSS3 implementation.

Comment: I'm still using the JS to trigger the CSS3 currently but some of the other suggestions seem pretty good :).